# Is there any faster way to process pandas dataframe into large csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to make following code faster to export into csv with (average file size 800MB) containing 100+ columns.
...................................................................
,.................................................................
.................................................................

```
            INPUT:

            DATE_TIME;          DATA1;        DATA2         
            12.18.2018 00:00:00;XXXXXXXXXXXX;YYYYYYYY   
            12.18.2018 00:00:00;XXXXXXXXXXXX;YYYYYYYY   
            12.18.2018 00:00:00;XXXXXXXXXXXX;YYYYYYYY   
            12.18.2018 01:00:00;XXXXXXXXXXXX;YYYYYYYY   

            OUTPUT will be no header:

            DATE,        TIME,   DATA1,      DATA2      
            2018-12-18,00:00:00,XXXXXXXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY   
            2018-12-18,00:00:00,XXXXXXXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY   
            2018-12-18,00:00:00,XXXXXXXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY   
            2018-12-18,01:00:00,XXXXXXXXXXXX,YYYYYYYY
```

`CODE`

```
import pandas
import glob

dfraw = []  

rawCSV = glob.glob('C:\RAW\*.csv')

rawCSV

for filename in rawCSV:
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')
    dfraw.append(data)

totalFile = len(dfraw)
x=0
dfclean=[]
for x in range(totalFile):
    tempdf =dfraw[x]["DATE_TIME"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
    tempdf[0] = tempdf[0].str.replace('.','-')
    dfraw[x].drop(columns =["DATE_TIME"], inplace = True)
    dfraw[x].insert(loc=0, column='DATE_ONLY', value=tempdf[0])
    dfraw[x].insert(loc=1, column='TIME_ONLY', value=tempdf[1])
    dfraw[x]['DATE_TIME'] = dfraw[x]['DATE_TIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    dfclean.append(dfraw[x])
concatdf=pandas.concat(dfclean, axis=0)

#dfclean.columns = dfclean.iloc[0]
#dfclean = dfclean[1:]
concatdf.to_csv('C:\CLEAN\__result.csv', index=False , header=False)
```

Comment: Can you give a small sample of input and expected output?

Comment: Assuming `concatdf=pandas.concat(dfclean, axis=0)` is outside the loop, you're unlikely to get it to be much faster than what you've got. If it's inside the loop you should move it outside the loop and it will go much faster. Also is the goal to get `'DATE_TIME'` to be empty? Cause it looks like that's what you're getting now.

Comment: @roganjosh...please find the expected data output

Comment: @CJ59, no its not being removed, i just splited from original between DATE and TIME. and also i just combine several csv as input  into one bigger csv as output

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the input, output, and code. They should be in separate indented blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the fastest you can get; I think it should work. It's writing files out as it reads them in, instead of piling up everything in memory until the end and doing `concat` (which is a bit slow)

```
import pandas
import glob

rawCSV = glob.glob('C:\RAW\*.csv')

for filename in rawCSV:
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')
    date_time = data['DATE_TIME'].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
    data.drop(columns =["DATE_TIME"], inplace = True)
    data.insert(loc=0, column='DATE_ONLY', value=date_time[0].str.replace('.','-'))
    data.insert(loc=1, column='TIME_ONLY', value=date_time[1])
    with open('C:\CLEAN\__result.csv', 'a') as fh:
        data.to_csv(fh, index=False , header=False)
```

It would probably be worth putting some checks in to make sure that you're not appending to a file that's already there and whatnot.

Comment: thanks it's is much faster..., add some missing codes